# neo4j batch operation get_or_create flag overrides existing node with different id

Tags: neo4j, batch-updates

I'm using the neo4j batch operations endpoint.
I want to index properties to an existing node if they have not been indexed before, ie. I'm using this [endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html#rest-api-add-an-existing-node-to-unique-index-not-indexed), with the exception of using `?uniqueness=get_or_create` flag.

It works, when when I'm issuing two such batch requests in a row for two different nodes, **the second one never gets indexed**!

Here is the payload for the the two batch requests:

```
FIRST ONE:
[
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'registeredInShop',
            value: '52a5f4e19e3fc8406a000006'
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'idInShop',
            value: '1'
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'email',
            value: 'me@shop.com'
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'createdOn',
            value: 1386607841880
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'attributes_isSpam',
            value: false
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'attributes_isHardBounced',
            value: false
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'attributes_isSubscribedAlerts',
            value: true
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'attributes_isSubscribed',
            value: true
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'attributes_isCustomer',
            value: false
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2388',
            key: 'id',
            value: '52a5f4e19e3fc8406a000008'
        }
    }
]





// SECOND ONE


[
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
            key: 'registeredInShop',
            value: '52a5f4e19e3fc8406a000006'
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'email',
                value: 'me2@shop.com'
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'createdOn',
                value: 1386607842460
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'attributes_isSpam',
                value: false
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'attributes_isHardBounced',
                value: false
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'attributes_isSubscribedAlerts',
                value: true
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'attributes_isSubscribed',
                value: true
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'attributes_isCustomer',
                value: false
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
            body: {
                uri: 'http: //localhost: 7474/db/data/node/2390',
                key: 'id',
                value: '52a5f4e29e3fc8406a000016'
            }
        }
    ]
```

Any ideea as to why this is happening? If I remove `uniqueness=get_or_create` it works, but it's exactly what I want to achieve!

Comment: I wrote a test and found that `uniqueness=get_or_create` is not needed when indexing node properties. Am I mistaken?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: latest stable v1.9.5 community

Answer (score 1):

See: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html#rest-api-refer-to-items-created-earlier-in-the-same-batch-job and scroll down to the example in the payload that indexes a relationship.

As far as your REST API request payloads go, it looks like you're missing the `id` property in your JSON. Also, you do not need to explicitly set the `uri` to the full URI of your Neo4j instance, just use the relative path to your nodes.

Your request should look like this:

```
[
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users?uniqueness=get_or_create',
        body: {
            uri: '/node/2388',
            key: 'registeredInShop',
            value: '52a5f4e19e3fc8406a000006'
        },
        id: 2388
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        to: '/index/node/users',
        body: {
            uri: '/node/2388',
            key: 'idInShop',
            value: '1'
        },
        id: 2388
    }
]
```

That should resolve your issues.

It's worth noting that this will not create the `user` index. You will need to ensure your index is created in advance to running these batch operations. Also, you'll need to update the index using this same process if your property on the node changes. Let me know in the comments whether or not this resolves your issue.

Cheers,

Kenny

Comment: AFAIK the `id` property is used to refer to the result of a previous operation in the same batch. I don't need this, I'm referring to an existing node, whose id/URL I already know and I want add it's properties to an existing index. I think you're confusing the node id with the batch operations {[JOB ID]} feature which **are not the same**!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. How many items do you have in an average batch? I'm wondering if it makes more sense to upgrade to 2.0 and then use Cypher. Also, Michael Hunger may be able to help more with your current issue.

Comment: It varies, anywhere between 5 to 50 operationsn in a batch.